# Checking a solution for $x'' + 4x' + 5 = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $x'' + 4x' + 5 = 0 $, I applied standard methods:

$ \lambda^2 + 4\lambda + 5 = 0 \, \, \Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2} = -2 \pm i $

So a complex solution is $\hat x(t) = c_1 e^{(-2+i)t} + c_2 e^{(-2-i)t}$

And a real solution is $x(t) = Re(\hat x(t)) + Im (\hat x(t)) = e^{-2t}(d_1\cos(t) + d_2\sin(t))$ with $d_1 := c_1 +c_2 $ and $d_2 := c_1 - c_2 $.

However, if I check my solution, I get a contradiction:

$x'(t) = e^{-2t}(-d_1\sin(t) -2d_1\cos(t) + d_2\cos(t) -2d_2\sin(t))$

$x''(t) = e^{-2t}(3d_1 \cos(t) + 4d_1 \sin(t) + 3d_2 \sin(t) - 4d_2 \cos(t))$

If I insert those expressions in my original equation, I obtain $d_1 \cos(t) + d_2 \sin(t) = 1 $.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: You are not using the correct formula. It'd be fine it you had $\;y''+4y'+5\color{red}y=0\;$ , but what you have here is the non-homogeneous one $\;y''+5y'=-5\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first solve the homogeneous part:

$$x^2+4x=x(x+4)=0\implies y_h(x)=C_1+C_2e^{-4t}$$

and now a particular solution to the non-homogeneous part, which in this case is very easy:

$$y_p(t)=-\frac54t$$

Thus the general solution

$$y=y_h+y_p=C_1+C_2e^{-4t}-\frac54t$$

Check:

$$y''+4y'+5=16C_2e^{-4t}-16C_2e^{-4t}-5+5=0$$